# Angular JS ng-repeat in directive, ng-model not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a custom directive to style specific radio buttons to look like a select element with a size attr, but I am having trouble storing the user's choice on the scope.

Please see code here: http://jsbin.com/xuxag/7/edit

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://jsbin.com/fuyefare/1/edit
I updated the isolated scope you defined and passed the obj as the input to the directive